# Prove that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n ^{1/k}}= a^{1/k}$ if $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n}= a$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n ^{1/k}}= a^{1/k}$ if
> $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n}= a$

The book tells me to use $x^k - y^k = (x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+ \dots + y^{k-1})$ with $x= a_n ^{1/k}$ and $y= a^{1/k}$. I did that and I rearranged to get an expression for $|a_n ^{1/k}-a^{1/k}|$. After that I divided the problem into two cases: $a=0$ and $a>0$. If $a>0$ then there exist positive integers $m$ and $N$ such that $a_n >m$ for all $n>N$. Using this, we can find a lower bound $L$ for the denominator of the expression for $|a_n ^{1/k}-a^{1/k}|$ for $n > N$. Then  $|a_n ^{1/k}-a^{1/k}|< |a_n-a|\frac{1}{L}$ and the rest is easy. However, I can't deal with the case when $a=0$. How can I complete this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a=0$ you may reason as follows. If $a_n\rightarrow0$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is  $n_\varepsilon$  such that $a_n < \min(1,\varepsilon^k)$ for all $n\geq n_\varepsilon$. Thus
$$
a^{1/k}_n <  \varepsilon
$$
for all $n\geq n_\varepsilon$. This means that $\lim_na^{1/k}_n=0$.